# Read multiple holding register in pymodbus

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I'm using ModbusSerialClient of [pymodbus](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.2/examples/tk-frontend.html) library. I've multiple registers that I want to read.

I'm able to read one register at a time, but not able to figure out how to read all the registers at a single time for better performance.

```
registers = [3900,3902,3904,3906,3926,3860]
client = ModbusSerialClient(method='rtu',port='/dev/ttyUSB0', timeout=1, parity='N', baudrate=19200, unit=1)
client.connect()

for register in registers:
    response = client.read_holding_registers(register, 2, unit=0x01)
```

I've tried something like this

```
add_min, add_max = min(registers), max(registers)
no_bytes = add_max - add_min
response = client.read_holding_registers(add_min, no_bytes, unit=0x01)
```

But it's throwing "Illegal Address" error.

Comment: You can read at most 125 registers (as per modbus specs. Note `1 register == 2 bytes`) If you are trying to read more than 125 registers pymodbus would throw `InvalidAddress` exception. Make sure `1< no_bytes<=125`.

Comment: You are assuming that all registers between 3860 and 3926 exists. If at least one of them is not mapped in the device an invalid address exception is returned.

Comment: Try this: `no_bytes = (add_max - add_min) + 2` instead of `no_bytes = add_max - add_min`, because in the maximum registers you need also to read two count. And consider maximum count of reading that not be more that `125` in each request.